# Novo esquema de horário - Banco de Dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho um sistema de pedidos, onde o horário de entrega do produto é selecionado num input normal do `type='time'`, e armazanado no banco de dados no tipo time também. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, porém terei que mudar e tem que ser da seguinte forma:

Usuario seleciona num select o horario que será do seguinte modo:

```
 08:00 - 09:00
 09:00 - 10:00
```

... e assim em diante fechando as 24h do dia

Minha duvida é como fazer esse select, se tenho que fazer manualmente num select ou se existe algum plugin.

**A dúvida mais importante** é em que tipo de dados eu poderia salvar esse novo método de horário no banco de dados

Comment: tipo de dados varchar - O select html faça manualmente, pois devem ser apenas 10 faixas no horário das 8hs às 18hs.  Pode testar em http://kithomepage.com/sos/Novo-esquema-de-horario-Banco-de-Dados.php

Comment: Você pode guardar a data completa fornecendo na UI apenas a hora e concatenando com a data atual no formato Y-M-D.
Nesse caso, use o tipo de dados datetime no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma tabela com estes horários e liste-os no select, assim caso tenha que que adicionar mais horários depois fica fácil, bastará adiciona-los à tabela.

Salve-os em formato time, se não precisa dos segundos basta formata-lo na hora de listar.

Answer (score 0):

O select é criado normalmente com o type = time, e os horários serão guardados em uma nova tabela que tenha referência com a tabela de usuário.